# function RemoveXSS - tweak to allow hyphens or spaces?

Tags: php, xss, filtering, antixsslibrary

The website I code on has a function applied that prevents all non-printable characters.
http://pastebin.com/FemaR8s0 < This is the version we have. 
 This prevents hyphens and spaces from being allowed in a name field and I was wondering if there was a way to modify the function to allow hyphens in the name field? It works if you change the name in the database, of course, but not when you try and log in or use the name on the site...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is too broad. Btw, that's not the best function for the job. It's also not intended to clean up name fields. Also it does not remove spaces or hyphens. `print removeXSS("name -field");` outputs `name -field`. So at the least you might have to reexplain what you meant with name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using hand-crafted XSS/SQL injection filters.  This function is an accident waiting to happen.  Replace it with [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and you'll be more secure and appropriate uses of hyphens and spaces will work just fine.

Comment: I didn't put in the function, it was a scripter working on the site before, but they're not really around atm, so I'm at a bit of a loss, really... I'd love some pointers about what would be better though and i will definitely check out the purifier. Thanks so much and sorry for being so vague, just that function seemed the only thing that could be interfering with the characters showing up...

Comment: @user1054798 I understand you didn't write it -- you're a maintainer who has been put in a mine-field.  I'm just pointing out one of the mines and a way to get around it.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the HTML purifier, I shall definitely bring it up with the site owner :D also, I've just checked another code and there is a $trim(strip_tags) function, I assume this is the one that disallows hyphens, etc? the html purifier website says not to use the strip tags, I think, but how would I go about replacing them all? I'm really sorry for all these questions and if it should be really obvious, I'm just tentative so long as I don't know something relatively fully... Thanks for all the help so far!